# How can I update a specific column in an activerecord in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model called **Agency**.

One of the rows from an **Agency** active record looks as follows:

```
#<Agency id: 1, name: "Hello", contact_person: "Abhimanyu", phone_number: "946159", email: "Abhimanyu@purple.com ", local_package: false, outstation: true, remarks: nil, status: 1>
```

Here I want to change the value of `status` to `0` . How can I do that?

Comment: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_column

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ruby on Rails provides many methods for updating an activerecord. You can get differences of each method from [this blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20160419042240/https://www.hoanghiep.org/2016/04/05/different-between-update-update_columns-update_column-update_attributes-assign_attributes).

```ruby
agency = Agency.find(1)
```

1. [update](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update)

   ```ruby
   agency.update(status: 0)
   ```
2. [update_attribute](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attribute)

   ```ruby
   agency.update_attribute(:status, 0)
   ```
3. [update_column](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_column)

   ```ruby
   agency.update_column(:status, 0)
   ```
4. [update_columns](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_columns)

   ```
   agency.update_columns(status: 0)
   ```

Comment: There is a link to the Wayback Machine for the broken blog post link, but it seems to be effectively broken(?).

Comment: Note: For some reason, the [Ruby on Rails tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) has its syntax highlighting set to "default", not "ruby" or "[lang-ruby](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109)", thus the apparent *weird* syntax highlighting ***by default***.

Comment: Is the reference I used legitimate? Is there a more authoritative source that could be used instead? For instance, version-independent.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use this

`Agency.find(1).update_column(:status, 0)`

Answer (score 3):

You need the [`update_column`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_column) method. Try this:

```
agency = Agency.find(1)
agency.update_column(:status, 0)
```

You should spend some time reading the [Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org).

Answer (score 2):

To update, you can use:

```
agency.update_column(:status, 0)
```

But update_column **will ignore all the validations** that you may have on your model.

If you don’t want to ignore your model validations, I recommend you to use:

```
agency.update status: 0
```

The method update_attributes is deprecated on rails 6 (https://blog.saeloun.com/2019/04/15/rails-6-deprecates-update-attributes.html)

To find the record that you want to update, you can use `.find` or `.where` methods. If you can find by ID use:

```
agency = Agency.find(1)
```

If you need to find by other fields, use `.where`:

```
agency = Agency.where(email: 'Abhimanyu@purple.com').first
```

The `.first` is used since the `.where` will return a Array with objects, and you need to select an object inside. If the object that you want isn't the first one, you can use `.last`.